# X axis gets affected when I add axhline to the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this problem where the X axis gets affected when I add `axhline` to the plot. All the code I use is down below. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import talib as ta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as web

data = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo")
data["RSI"] = ta.RSI(data["Close"])

if True:
  plt.axhline(y=70, color="r", linestyle="--")
  plt.axhline(y=30, color="g", linestyle="--")
plt.plot(data["RSI"])

plt.show()
```

[Pic of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsJKo.png)

As you see I now get a plot where the X axis has been affected

But if I remove the lines I get a normal plot

[Pic of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwfmF.png)

Why does the X axis get affected when I add the lines? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Did you try changing `xmin` of [`plt.axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html)?

Comment: Yes, it does not help

Answer (score 0):

```py
import talib as ta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader as web

data = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo")
data["RSI"] = ta.RSI(data["Close"])

plt.plot(data["RSI"])

if True:
  plt.axhline(y=70, color="r", linestyle="--")
  plt.axhline(y=30, color="g", linestyle="--")


plt.show()
```

Comment: plt.plot(data["RSI"]) has to come before plt.axhline